# How do I get user information in Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I have some Firebase Crashlytics logs in my database.

```
{
"_id": "5ae6dea55af80300028a52a2",
"type": "type.googleapis.com/firebase.crashlytics.functions.v1.RegressedIssueEvent",
"issueId": "5ad8590d36c7b2352749218c",
"issueTitle": "CrashTest.java line 30",
"appInfo": {
    "appName": "com.test.finder",
    "appId": "com.test.finder",
    "appPlatform": "android",
    "latestAppVersion": "1.0 (1)"
},
"createTime": "2018-04-30T09:15:10.419Z",
"resolvedTime": "2018-04-30T09:14:17.430Z",
"velocityAlert": null,
"updatedAt": "2018-04-30T09:15:17.225Z",
"createdAt": "2018-04-30T09:15:17.225Z",
"__v": 0
```

As you can see from the JSON above, there is no user object as you can find in Firebase events. I want to identify the users specifically to address the issue. So, I need the user information in the logs. 
Is there any possibility to make Firebase send the userInfo in crash reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the user ids from Crashlytics and get it returned with crash reports.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#set_user_ids